# How i make a top servers in my bot.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How make a Top 10 most popular servers ?

[image]

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with?  Getting the servers, sorting them, or creating the embed?

Comment: sorting them  ;-;

Comment: Show us your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by the `member_count` attribute of the `Server` objects.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def servers(ctx, n: int=10):
    servers = list(bot.servers)
    n = min(n, len(servers))
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Top {n} servers")
    for server in sorted(servers, key=lambda x: x.member_count, reverse=True)[:n]:
        embed.add_field(name=server.name, value=f"{server.member_count} members", inline=False)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thanks <3 i love u